# Drop Down Menu Categories / Sub Categories

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I am trying to do is have a drop down menu divided. In this example there are Five Options how can I split the drop down into categories? For example option 1 and 2 pop out of the environment category and option 3 and 4 sports category and 5 college category? http://jsfiddle.net/fc3550sk/

For example:

Drop down: Please Select when you click it Menus will be Environment, Sports, Colleges..
Then hover over Environment and it will let you choose from option 1 or 2... or hover over sports and it will let you chose from 3 or 4 and so on..

This is what I have so far:

```
      <select name="SPECIAL" id="SPECIAL">
  <option>Please Select</div>
    <option data-img="/images/img/AnimalFriend.png" value="1">AnimalFriend</option>
    <option data-img="/images/img/Aquaculture.png" value="2">Aquaculture</option>
    <option data-img="/images/img/ProtectOurOceans.png" value="3">Protect Our Oceans</option>
    <option data-img="/images/img/ConserveWildlife.png" value="4">Conserve Wildlife</option>
          </select>
      <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_special" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Specialty Plate</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary accept">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
        $('#SPECIAL').on('change', function() {
            if ($('option:selected', this).is('[data-img]')) {
                $('#modal_special').find('.modal-body').html('<p>Image will go here:</p>')
                .append('<img alt="coming soon" src="' + $('option:selected', this).data('img') + '"/>')
                .end().modal('show');
            }
        });
        $('.accept').on('click',function() {
            //do something
            $('#modal_special').modal('hide');
        });
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Why won't use a menu plugin ? Or simulate the behavior of the dropdown with custom div ?

Comment: Just make a quick search on jquery menu plugin. You will probably found what you needed.

Comment: If you use a plugin you need to add a reference to it and implemented it the way it should be. Normally, there doc that come with the plugin to show you how to use it. The plugin will probably use li or div. You can't convert you select into a menu.

Comment: The bootstrap menu is a click menu with two levels, there are some bootplys around with more than 2 levels. Hover is not a good idea if you want to support touch devices. Here's one you can play with: http://jsbin.com/culiw/edit

Comment: Is it important that it's an actual html select input, or can it be a custom component that just feels like a drop-down? Because I know of way to replicate this functionality with a custom component (all done in jquery), but as far as I know, you can't grab the "highlighted" value of a standard drop-down to perform custom functionality in a way that would be supported in all browsers (notice how I said "highlighted" and not "selected"). So I am happy to show you a custom component solution in jquery if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to attach a "hover" event listener to a standard drop-down menu, but it's not too much work to implement your own custom drop-down with jquery, html and css.

### Custom Drop-down Advantage #01

**You get to assign as many custom values to each entry as you want.**

In your example, you have "Specialty Plates", and you may want to assign a price, a special code assigned to that plate, an image assigned to that plate, and so on. With an HTML/jQuery version, you can create your custom drop-downs with simple `<span>` tags like this:

```
<span data-code="SPRT01" data-image="" data-price="34.00">Sports 01</span>
<span data-code="SPRT02" data-image="" data-price="35.00">Sports 02</span>
<span data-code="SPRT03" data-image="" data-price="36.00">Sports 03</span>
```

Notice how each entry has three custom values assigned to it: *data-code, data-image, and data-price*. If you use an html drop-down, you don't have as much freedom. There are ways to extend the values associated with a standard drop-down, but getting at the values is messy, and you will still not have access to the hover behavior your features require.

### Custom Drop-down Advantage #02

**You can actually use the hover behavior in any way you want.**

In your example, you want the "submenus" to show up when certain values in your drop-down are selected, but as far as I know, there isn't a way to gain access to the values that are "hovered" in a standard drop-down, and looking for an HTML-only solution just doesn't exist, so you would have to use javascript in one way or another.

Using jQuery, you can easily get to the values in your custom drop-down elements like this:

```
$("span").hover(
    function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        console.log("You have hovered on: ", text); 
    }, 
    function(){
        // You have hovered off the span        
    }
);
```

## My Solution to Your Problem

Putting these ideas into practice, I put together a simple demo of how you can create a custom drop-down using your applications parameters.

[**You can review a jsfiddle of the demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/j585zy0y/2/)

The Basic idea is that you create a hierarchy in html with the structure of your Top-level options (Environment, Sports, Colleges) in the div `.drop_down_scroll_container`, and you place all your sub-level divs (Environment 01, Environment 02, etc) below that div in a div classed `.dropdown-subcategory`. Where the magic happens, is that javascript looks up the index of the top-level option, and then reveals the `dropdown-subcategory` with that same index.

For example, in the following snippet of html, you can see the index positions of each of the spans within the `drop_down_scroll_container` div:

```
<div class="drop_down_scroll_container">
   <span>Environment</span> <!-- index 0 -->
   <span>Sports</span>      <!-- index 1 -->
   <span>Colleges</span>    <!-- index 2 -->
</div>
```

So then, when you hover over any of those Top-level options (Environment, Sports, Colleges) you can ask jQuery to reveal the corresponding submenu div, which are sitting below the `.drop_down_scroll_container` div in div containers with a class of `.dropdown-subcategory`

```
<div id="dropdown" class="specialtyPlatesCategories">

    <div class="selectHeader">Click to Select Plates:</div>

    <!-- THIS IS WHERE YOU WILL PUT YOUR TOP-LEVEL OPTIONS -->
    <div class="drop_down_scroll_container">
        <span>Environment</span>
        <span>Sports</span>
        <span>Colleges</span>
    </div>

    <!-- THIS DIV IS AT INDEX 0 of: #dropdown.dropdown-subcategory  -->
    <!-- Will fade in when the drop_down_scroll_container index 0 is hovered -->
    <div id="env_subcategories" class="dropdown-subcategory">
           <span data-code="ENV01" data-image="" data-price="31.00">Environment 01</span>
       <span data-code="ENV02" data-image="" data-price="32.00">Environment 02</span>
       <span data-code="ENV03" data-image="" data-price="33.00">Environment 03</span>
    </div>

    <!-- THIS DIV IS AT INDEX 1 of: #dropdown.dropdown-subcategory  -->
    <!-- Will fade in when the drop_down_scroll_container index 1 is hovered -->
    <div id="sports_subcategories" class="dropdown-subcategory">
       <span data-code="SPRT01" data-image="" data-price="34.00">Sports 01</span>
       <span data-code="SPRT02" data-image="" data-price="35.00">Sports 02</span>
       <span data-code="SPRT03" data-image="" data-price="36.00">Sports 03</span>
    </div>

    <!-- THIS DIV IS AT INDEX 2 of: #dropdown.dropdown-subcategory  -->
    <!-- Will fade in when the drop_down_scroll_container index 2 is hovered -->
    <div id="colleges_subcategories" class="dropdown-subcategory">
       <span data-code="COLL01" data-image="" data-price="37.00">Colleges 01</span>
       <span data-code="COLL02" data-image="" data-price="38.00">Colleges 02</span>
       <span data-code="COLL03" data-image="" data-price="39.00">Colleges 03</span>
    </div>

</div>
```

If none of that made any sense, here is another way of looking it at:

When the first item in the `.drop_down_scroll_container` is hovered, jQuery looks for the first instance of a `.dropdown-subcategory` below it. When the second item in the `.drop_down_scroll_container` is hovered, then jQuery will reveal the second instance of the `.dropdown-subcategory`, and so on. This lets you build as many options as you want, without having to worry about giving everything specific names, only the order matters in this case. So when the "Environment" option (who's index equals `0`) is hovered, the `.dropdown-subcategory` with an index of `0` will show. That is the basic idea.

**So now for the jQuery that puts it all together:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // When the header for the custom drop-down is clicked
    $(".selectHeader").click(function() {

        // cache the actual dropdown scroll container
        var dropdown = $(this).parent().find(".drop_down_scroll_container");

        // Toggle the visibility on click
        if (dropdown.is(":visible")) {
            dropdown.slideUp();
            $(this).parent().find(".dropdown-subcategory").fadeOut();
        } else {
            dropdown.slideDown();
        }

    });

    // When a top-level menu item is hovered, decide if its
    // coorespnding submenu should be visible or hidden
    $(".drop_down_scroll_container span").hover(

        // hover on
        function() {

            // Remove the "highlighted class from all other options
            $(this).parent().find("span").removeClass("highlighted").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("highlighted").addClass("selected");

            // Get the index of the hovered span
            var index = $(this).index();

            // Use the hovered index to reveal the 
            // dropdown-subcategory of the same index
            var subcategorydiv = $(this).parent().parent().find(".dropdown-subcategory").eq(index);
            hideallSubmenusExceptMenuAtIndex($(this).parent().parent(), index);
            subcategorydiv.slideDown();
        },

        // hover off
        function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass("highlighted")) {
                var index = $(this).index();
                var subcategorydiv = $(this).parent().parent().find(".dropdown-subcategory").eq(index);
                subcategorydiv.slideUp();
            }
    });

    // Hide all submenu items except for the submenu item at _index
    // This will hide any of the previously opened submenu items
    function hideallSubmenusExceptMenuAtIndex(formElement, _index) {
        formElement.find(".dropdown-subcategory").each(
            function(index) {
                if (_index != index) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            }
        );
    }

    // When any menu item is hovered
    $("span").hover(
        function() {
            $(".hoveredOver").text($(this).text());
        },
        function() {
            $(".hoveredOver").text("");
        }
    );


    // When a sub-menu option is clicked
    $(".dropdown-subcategory span").click(function() {
        $(".dropdown-subcategory span").removeClass("selected");
        $(".clickedOption").text($(this).text());
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".selectHeader").text($(this).text());
        closeDropDown($(this).parent().parent());
        showSpecialPlateModal($(this).text(), $(this).attr("data-image"), $(this).attr("data-price"), $(this).attr("data-code"));
    });

    // Close the dropdowns contained in divToSearch
    function closeDropDown(divToSearch) {
        divToSearch.find(".drop_down_scroll_container").fadeOut();
        divToSearch.find(".dropdown-subcategory").fadeOut();
    };

    // Populate and Launch the bootstrap Modal Dialog Specialty Plates 
    function showSpecialPlateModal(name, image, price, code) {
      $('#modal_special').find('.modal-body')
        .html('<h2>' + name + '</h2>')
        .append('<br/>Special Plate Code: <span class="code">' + code + '</span><br/>')
        .append('<p>Image will go here:</p><br/><img alt="" src="' + image + '"/>')
        .append('<br/><br/>Price: <span class="price">' + price + '</span><br/>')
        .end().modal('show');
    }

    // When the modal "Accept" button is pressed
    $('.accept').on('click', function() {
        var modal_element = $('#modal_special');
        var name = modal_element.find("h2").text();
        var price = modal_element.find("span.price").text();
        var code = modal_element.find("span.code").text();
        $('#modal_special').modal('hide').end(alert(name + " was selected for a price of " + price));
    });

});
```

Note: There may already be some open-source solutions that take care of this problem in a more elegant fashion. But this was my approach at solving an issue like this. As you can see, it only takes a little bit of setup to get going. You can easily control the styling of the drop-down in css, and you can extend this to do anything you want.

**[Again, you can review a jsfiddle to see all of this code in action here.](http://jsfiddle.net/j585zy0y/2/)**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is exactly what your were looking for but you could try something like this:

```html
    <select name="SPECIAL" id="SPECIAL">
      <option>Please Select</div>
        <optgroup label="Environmental">
          <option 
            data-img="/images/img/AnimalFriend.png" 
            value="1">AnimalFriend</option>
          <option 
            data-img="/images/img/Aquaculture.png" 
            value="2">Aquaculture</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Sports">
          <option 
            data-img="/images/img/ProtectOurOceans.png" 
            value="3">Protect Our Oceans</option>
          <option 
            data-img="/images/img/ConserveWildlife.png" 
            value="4">Conserve Wildlife</option>
        </optgroup>
       </select>
```